# Avoid a WPF Storyboard animation when another one is running

Tags: wpf, storyboard

I am new to WPF Storyboard, I have the following two storyboards defined.

```
<Storyboard x:Key="sbShowLeftMenu" Completed="Storyboard_Completed"  >
    <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" From="-100,0,0,0" To="0,0,0,0" DecelerationRatio=".9" Duration="0:0:1" />
</Storyboard>
<Storyboard x:Key="sbHideLeftMenu" Completed="Storyboard_Completed">
    <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" From="0,0,0,0" To="-100,0,0,0" AccelerationRatio=".9" Duration="0:0:1" />
</Storyboard>
```

I am finding situations when both of them are triggered simultaneously. How can I ensure that one is triggered only after the other is completed? I know there is completed event, but not sure how to use it.

Comment: If you mean to do it in XAML, very likely no. You should handle it in your code behind

Comment: So you mean by setting some kind of flag as the animation is running?

Comment: Can you post the code for `Storyboard_completed`? You do it from there

Comment: I don't have any as of now. I am thinking how to handle it.

Comment: I'll post an answer but as I'm not on my dev machine, there might be errors which I will edit when I find out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Your XAML (edited)

```
<Storyboard x:Key="sbShowLeftMenu" Completed="Storyboard_Completed"  >
    <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" From="-100,0,0,0" To="0,0,0,0" DecelerationRatio=".9" Duration="0:0:1" />
</Storyboard>
<Storyboard x:Key="sbHideLeftMenu">
    <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" From="0,0,0,0" To="-100,0,0,0" AccelerationRatio=".9" Duration="0:0:1" />
</Storyboard>
```

Note that I've removed the second `Storyboard_Completed` (except you are going to be needing it).

## Code behind (.xaml.cs)

```
private void Storyboard_Completed(...)
{
    sbHideLeftMenu.Begin();
}
```